# Drag and drop from browser to Java application

Tags: java, html, drag-and-drop

I am working on a Java application that has the ability to accept text (in a JTextComponent) that is selected, dragged and dropped from a browser such as Chrome and IE.

Is it possible for my application to know the URL of the text I am dragging and dropping?

In other words, does the export of data from the browser contain the URL along with the highlighted text that I am dragging and would it be possible for me to access this URL in my Java application?

I know this is likely based on which browser I am using. I am just curious if this is a possibility in any of the common browsers (Chrome, Firefox , IE, etc.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to test it, maybe start by having a look at the [Drag and Drop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html) tutotrials, devise your own component and inspect the `DataFlavour`s which are available when you drop text onto it

Comment: Thank you! I wrote a program to test the flavors and with Chrome 56.0.2924.87, I am picking up "selection html", "string", "all html", "fragment html" DataFlavors. The html ones include the Source URL.